# edit htaccess to make it case insensitive

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My actual .htaccess using for the URL rewriting is case sensitive :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ /BB/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
```

I would like to make it case insensitive.

Have you an idea please ?

Comment: Is it really that hard to just go look at the official docs? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc honestly... We're not your personal search agents... googling "mod_rewrite case insensitive" would have brought you right to the docs

Comment: Why is your index not handling the entire route? Dont do it in .htaccess do it in your router

Comment: Hello, thank you for your replies.  

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ /BB/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC] is not resolving my problem, strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it case insensitive, you would add the `NC` flag at the end of the line:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ /BB/index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, strangely, my site still does not working... I have those messaes 
Warning: require_once(Models/PDO/acces_pdo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dubinfo/www/projects/BB/Autoloader.php on line 15

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Models/PDO/acces_pdo.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php') in /home/dubinfo/www/projects/BB/Autoloader.php on line 15

Comment: are those required files located in `/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php`? if not you need to move them there, so for example you would have one of the files located at: `/usr/local/php5.4/lib/php/Models/PDO/acces_pdo.php`

Comment: @user3553866 U should determine the problem better and ask the right questions. .htaccess does not have anything to do with autoloading/requiring files.

Comment: @DarkBee my problem is that this code $controller_obj = new \Controllers\Accueil_controller(); is not good, I have to put a little a to accueil to get my site working... is this a .htaccess problem or not ? Thank you !

Comment: @user3553866 this is not an htaccess problem, it is a problem of not including the correct file. You are more than likely including the wrong location.